# Nginx with upload module does not let me upload files bigger than client_body_buffer_size

Tags: nginx, configuration, upload, buffer

I am trying to upload files via Nginx upload module. It is working fine until now, the file is uploaded, when the upload is finished the request is proxied to my node app.

The only problem is that if I upload a file (let's say an image), only the N first bytes will be correct in my image, the rest is black pixels. I found out that N is the value of client_body_buffer_size.

Here is my conf for this virtual host:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name example.com;

access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/example.nginx_error.log debug;

client_max_body_size 4G;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3112;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
}

location /uploadNginx {
  # For CORS
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
  if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    # Access control for CORS
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "cache-control, content-range, accept, origin, session-id, content-disposition, x-requested-wit$
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";

    # 10 minute pre-flight approval
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 600;

    return 204;
  }

  if ($request_method = POST) {
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Pragma no-cache;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    #add_header Cache-control "no-story, no-cache, must-revalidate";

    # Access control for CORS
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "$http_origin";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "cache-control, content-range, accept, origin, session-id, content-disposition, x-requested-wit$
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true";

    # 10 minute pre-flight approval
    add_header Access-Control-Max-Age 600;

    # Set specified fields in request body
    # This puts the original filename, new path+filename and content type
    # in the requests params
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

    upload_pass_form_field "^X-Progress-ID$|^authenticity_token$";
    upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;

    # Upload general conf
    upload_buffer_size 512k;
    upload_resumable off;
  }

  # Store files to this directory
  # The directory is hashed, subdirectories 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 should exist
  upload_store /var/tmp/nginx_uploads 1;

  # The upload_state folder is where your .state files will live. These files are used to track
  # the progress of chunked uploads. Note that you do not need a "1" here, as they all go into
  # the same folder.
  upload_state_store /var/upload_state;

  # set permissions on the uploaded files
  upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;

  upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^description$";

  upload_pass                @fast_upload_endpoint;
}

location @fast_upload_endpoint {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3112;
}
}
```

The upload looks like it takes the correct time for upload (even with buffer size of 8k the upload takes seconds for a 2M image), so I guess that the full image is uploaded, but seems not to be correctly gathered. Any hints about it ?

Answer (score 0):

if your `client_body_buffer_size` is smaller than request's body size, the entire body or partial will be write to disk. It might cause data corruption, but rarely.